# css position: fixed - задать центр потомка по центру родителя адаптивно

Tags: css3, адаптивная-верстка, центрирование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть кнопка на сайте, которая всегда должна быть на виду. 
Она смещается при прокрутке (скриптом js подставляется новый класс при прокрутке).

Проблема в том, что я никак не могу ее адаптивно центрировать ОТНОСИТЕЛЬНО РОДИТЕЛЯ после этого смещения.
Задаю стили для добавляемого при прокрутке класса:

```css
.scrolled {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
```

и получаю смещение относительно левого края элемента. 
А нужно сместить элемент относительно его центра.

Элемент - кнопка шириной 186 px. 
Соответственно, нужно его как-то позиционировать влево на (50% ширины окна браузера - 93 px;). Других решений пока не вижу.

Можно ли это сделать средствами css?

Пробовала transform, но это свойство не работает для position: fixed;

В общем, "сами мы  не местные, помогите, чем можете" :(
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаем контейнер на всю ширину экрана и позиционируем внизу, а все элементы внутри выравниваем по центру.

Способ 1: с помощью `text-align:center`

Способ 2: с помощью `flex-box`

```css
#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed">
    <a href="">ПО ЦЕНТРУ</a> 
</div>
```

```css
#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #ddd;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed">
    <a href="">ПО ЦЕНТРУ</a> 
</div>
```

UPD: согласно вашей задачи. Чтобы данный код сработал, нужно чтобы была указана ширина родительского блока.

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
}

#contant{
  width:200px;
}
#menu{
  background:#ddd;
}
#menu a{
  display:block;
  width:100px;
}

#fixed{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width: inherit; /*унаследовать ширину родителя. */
  background: #ddd;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div id="contant">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam tempora voluptas dolor temporibus, fugit sed nemo sit molestiae dolorem minima cumque libero vitae omnis voluptatum! Dignissimos fugiat, neque asperiores. Odio.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam tempora voluptas dolor temporibus, fugit sed nemo sit molestiae dolorem minima cumque libero vitae omnis voluptatum! Dignissimos fugiat, neque asperiores. Odio.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam tempora voluptas dolor temporibus, fugit sed nemo sit molestiae dolorem minima cumque libero vitae omnis voluptatum! Dignissimos fugiat, neque asperiores. Odio.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam tempora voluptas dolor temporibus, fugit sed nemo sit molestiae dolorem minima cumque libero vitae omnis voluptatum! Dignissimos fugiat, neque asperiores. Odio.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam tempora voluptas dolor temporibus, fugit sed nemo sit molestiae dolorem minima cumque libero vitae omnis voluptatum! Dignissimos fugiat, neque asperiores. Odio.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam tempora voluptas dolor temporibus, fugit sed nemo sit molestiae dolorem minima cumque libero vitae omnis voluptatum! Dignissimos fugiat, neque asperiores. Odio.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam tempora voluptas dolor temporibus, fugit sed nemo sit molestiae dolorem minima cumque libero vitae omnis voluptatum! Dignissimos fugiat, neque asperiores. Odio.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam tempora voluptas dolor temporibus, fugit sed nemo sit molestiae dolorem minima cumque libero vitae omnis voluptatum! Dignissimos fugiat, neque asperiores. Odio.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam tempora voluptas dolor temporibus, fugit sed nemo sit molestiae dolorem minima cumque libero vitae omnis voluptatum! Dignissimos fugiat, neque asperiores. Odio.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam tempora voluptas dolor temporibus, fugit sed nemo sit molestiae dolorem minima cumque libero vitae omnis voluptatum! Dignissimos fugiat, neque asperiores. Odio.</p>
    <div id='fixed'>
        <a href=''>ЦЕНТР</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='menu'>
    <a href="">1</a>
    <a href="">2</a>
    <a href="">3</a>
    <a href="">4</a>
    <a href="">5</a>
    <a href="">6</a>
    <a href="">7</a>
    <a href="">8</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Евгений! Я, видимо, неточно сформулировала вопрос.Прилагаю скриншот результата. На небольших экранах все отлично работает (там боковое меню смещается вниз, поэтому всё ОК). А на тех, что побольше получается, как на скрине.

Comment: Т.е, видимо, нужно выравнивать по центру относительно непосредственного родителя (у меня это блок article). А не окна браузера. Ума мне пока в этом не хватает :(

Comment: @Наталья меню фиксированной ширины?

Comment: @Наталья добавил еще один код.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду разбираться (углублять свои знания Css на досуге, а то ж самоучка). Фиксированной ширины на сайте нет нигде, насколько я помню. Для вящей адаптивности :) Сейчас решила вопрос иначе - "повесила" кнопку при прокрутке в правый нижний угол, раз уж позиционировать мне его не удалось. Доработаю всё остальное, и вернусь к этому моменту.

Comment: @Наталья посмотрите в сторону `position: sticky;` может поможет

Comment: Сейчас решила вопрос, подойдя с другого края. Раз не удалось мне добиться нужного результата при фиксации сверху, я просто перенесла позицию в правый нижний угол экрана. Пусть это и банально:) Впоследствии, возможно, попробую position: sticky;